# Hyphen in an object field passed into angular directive doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am passing two objects into a directive, but it doesn't seem to work, e.g.

```
<editable-directive user="globals.currentUser" owner="prioritisation['owner-object']"></editable-directive>
```

Both globals.currentUser and prioritisation['owner-object'] are objects, but owner-object doesn't seem to pass through due to the hyphen.

I'm on Angular 1.6 (historical reasons)

Answer (score -1):

Don't know the Entire Context of your question but why don't you pass the entire array to the directive

```
<editable-directive user="globals.currentUser" owner="prioritisation"></editable-directive>
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I can do that (and it works), but it's not an ideal solution as it's a huge object and I just want the relevant bit accessible to the directive. Just curious as to how to pass in a hyphenated object key.

Comment: I could also rename the key, but that is a whole different can or worms :-)

Comment: let me know if the following works prioritisation['owner\-object'] ..Not sure just a guess...